# Is there a function to "blockify" html?

Tags: block-editor

Let's say we have a string that contains

```
<h1>Here's a title</h1>
<p>Here's some text</p>
```

I'm looking for a function that parses this to whatever a block looks like (written from memory).

```
<!-- wp-paragraph -->
<p class="wp-block-paragraph">Here's some text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

Comment: WP has the "convert to block" functionality in core. Have you taken a look how it works?

Comment: Maybe this other answer can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54840853/17320082